# Why does map not include out_of_range?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following code that doesn't compile:

```
#include <map>

//#include <stdexcept>  // uncommenting this works

int main() {

    std::map<int, int> test;
    try {
        test.at(10);
    } catch(std::out_of_range& e) {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why does `std::map` not include `std::out_of_range`, even if it uses it? (The `.at()` can throw a `std::out_of_range`).

When I also include `<stdexcept>` it compiles, and works fine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225714/discussion-on-question-by-creepsy-why-does-map-not-include-out-of-range).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether a standard header does include another header is an implementation detail unless explicitly specified.

With templates its a little more involved, but just to point you in some direction, consider this toy example:

```
// header: my_map.h
struct my_map {
    int at(int);
};
```

Only in the source file the header for the exception has to be included:

```
// source: my_map.cpp
#include <stdexcept>
int my_map::at(int) {
    throw std::out_of_range("bla");
}
```

`std::map` surely looks different but it may hide the exception from the header as well.

---

> Is it also ok for a  header to not include a decl for std::pair

The headers that are specified to be included via [`<map>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/map) are `<compare>` (since C++20)  and `<initializer_list>` (since C++11). Nothing more.

`<map>` may include other headers and thats one of the "implementation details" mentioned in comments. The part of the standard that explicitly allows standard headers to include others is [todo.put reference here].

The simple rule of thumb that avoids such headace is: Include what you use.

---

> but throwing std::out_of_range is not an "implementation detail" - it is part of the specification of std::map!

Consider that this code compiles with [gcc 10.2](https://godbolt.org/z/jqdz6W):

```
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> test;
    try {
        test.at(10);
    } catch(...) {
        return 1;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

The `out_of_range` exception is thrown and catched, and 1 is returned. We know what `at` may throw and `catch(...)` will catch it, yet no include is needed for the exception.

On the other hand, the same compiler [rejects your example](https://godbolt.org/z/TWGshd), but [compiles it](https://godbolt.org/z/qGrosq) when we add a seemingly unrelated header:

```
#include <map>
#include <sstream>    // why this? 

int main() {

    std::map<int, int> test;
    try {
        test.at(10);
    } catch(std::out_of_range& e) {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, this only works by coincidence. Apparently `<sstream>` does include `<stdexcept>` somewhere along the line. But this may change with compiler version or between differernt compilers.

Comment: Plesae point to either the standard where it says this or to any available tutorial on the web where it gives a list of all headers you really must include for portable code if you include one of the others, e.g., a table somewhere that shows a row for std::map you really need to include utility, stdexcept, iterator, etc., a row for string, a row for stringstream, a row for vector etc etc.

Comment: @davidbak for `<map>` i used information from here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/map will add that link to the answer

Comment: @davidbak There are is no such set of required includes. You only need to `#include` the header when you use the feature that requires it. If your code is not using `std::map<K,V>::iterator` than you don't need to `#include<iterator>`, etc. You only include what you need.

Comment: @davidbak as I wrote the rule of thumb is: Include what you use. Thats it. Most likely lots of my code only works due to indirect includes, lets face it: portable code is an ideal and unless you port it you cannot be sure. Also a `<map>` that doesn't come with a definition for `std::pair` is possible but unlikely

Comment: @davidbak \[associative.map.syn] Header `<map>` synopsis lists all entities defined in that header. There is no row of `#include` directives that all must be present in a program that uses `std::map`. A minimal program that uses only `std::map` actually needs only `<map>`. You use another name from the standard, you look it up in the docs and add its header. Iterators are member types of `std::map` so there is no special header for them.

Comment: @davidbak fwiw I added an example that actually does catch the `out_of_range` without needing a definition for it. Note that same compiler with same flags rejects your code

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 you actually need to include `<iterator>` mostly when you define your own iterators. `std::map<K,V>::iterator` is a member of `std::map<K,V>`, you don't need a separate header for it.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I suppose your comment was for Francois. Including `<iterator>` for `std::map<K,V>::iterator` is indeed not a good example

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of `std::map` doesn't have to be all in the header file. Yes this is a class template, but it is free to use any internal non-template components.

Consequently, the header file doesn't have to mention `std::out_of_range` (it may well be hidden inside one of those non-template components) and so doesn't have to have its definition visible anywhere, or behave as if it includes `<stdexcept>`. It is explicitly allowed to, but there is no implicit or explicit obligation in the standard for it to do so. So it might, or might not.

In fact `g++-9` behaves as if `<map>` includes `<stdexcept>`, and `g++-10` does not, and in both cases they are correct.

Comment: It would sure be sweet if you (or the other commentators on the question) could please tell me where in the standard it says this?

Comment: @davidbak It is allowed by omission. When a standard header is required to include another, it is explicitly mentioned. Example : [`<map>` must `#include <initializer_list>`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/associative.map.syn). Otherwise, there is nothing to require or forbid headers from including each other. Its up to the implementation to decide what they want.

Comment: @davidbak Says what? That it is allowed to include other header files? \[res.on.headers] A C++ header may include other C++ headers.

Comment: @davidbak: Actually, it ends up being the other way around.  The standard doesn't _require_ map to include `<stdexcept>`, so implementations are not required to do so.

Comment: @davidbak: The one that people normally hit is that many other headers include the `std::string` class, but do not include `<string>` directly, and so people can write `std::cout << myString;`, and it fails because it can't find `operator<<(std::ostream&,std::string&)`, because the user never included `<string>`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does std::map not include std::out_of_range

Assuming you are using GCC 10, GCC developers decided to optimize header dependencies in C++ Standard Library code. From [Porting to GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/porting_to.html):

> Header dependency changes
>
> Some C++ Standard Library headers have been changed to no longer
> include the <stdexcept> header. As such, C++ programs that used
> components defined in <stdexcept> or <string> without explicitly
> including the right headers will no longer compile.
>
> Previously components such as std::runtime_error, std::string and
> std::allocator were implicitly defined after including unrelated
> headers such as <array> and <optional>. Correct code should include
> the appropriate headers for the classes being used.

Also from [GCC 10 Release Notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html):

> Reduced header dependencies, leading to faster compilation for some
> code.